# Method 'get_AdHocMapper' does not have an implementation."

Tags: postgresql, macos, .net-core, hotchocolate

I'm trying to use `HotChoclate` to implement GraphQL Server but I get this error:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unexpected Execution Error",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "managers"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "message": "Method 'get_AdHocMapper' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalDatabaseFacadeDependencies' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.",
        "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkRelationalServicesBuilder.TryAddCoreServices()\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.NpgsqlServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)\n   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Infrastructure.Internal.NpgsqlOptionsExtension.ApplyServices(IServiceCollection services)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.ApplyServices(IDbContextOptions options, ServiceCollection services)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<GetOrAdd>g__BuildServiceProvider|4_1(IDbContextOptions _, ValueTuple`2 arguments)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c.<GetOrAdd>b__4_0(IDbContextOptions contextOptions, ValueTuple`2 tuples)\n   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)\n   at AssistantContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 options) in /Users/mahmoud/testapi/db/dbcontext.cs:line 13\n   at lambda_method48(Closure, IServiceProvider, DbContextOptions`1)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextFactory`1.CreateDbContext()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextFactory`1.CreateDbContextAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at HotChocolate.Types.EntityFrameworkObjectFieldDescriptorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_1`1.<<UseDbContext>b__4>d.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.ExecuteResolverPipelineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.TryExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my service configuration:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<AssistantContext>( o => o.UseNpgsql("Host=127.0.0.1;Database=managingassistant;Username=root;Password=root"));
builder.Services
     .AddGraphQLServer()
     .AddQueryType<Query>()
     .RegisterDbContext<AssistantContext>(DbContextKind.Synchronized)
```

and this is my query file:

```cs
public class Query
{
    [UseDbContext(typeof(AssistantContext))]
    public IQueryable<Manager> GetManagers([Service(ServiceKind.Synchronized)] AssistantContext db)
    {
        return db.Managers;
    }
}
```

These are my env status:

- MacOS + VSCode + .Net 8.0
- Db: PostgreSQL

And these are my packages:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore" Version="13.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.Data.EntityFramework" Version="13.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="8.0.0-preview.4.23260.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.9">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

`HotChoclate.EntityFramework` causes this conflict in .Net 8. Downgrading to .Net 7 fixed the issue. Probably we should wait to get the.Net 8 ready version of Hotchoclate